# Could you theoretically map the internal distribution of mass in a black hole using Hawking radiation?

Tags: black-holes, information, hawking-radiation, unitarity

Assuming you could measure the qualities of the radiation emanating from all around a black hole, could this be used to determine the internal geometry or makeup of the mass inside?

Comment: No. Nothing leaves the interior of a classical black hole, by construction. Hawking radiation is a "surface" effect deduced from a semiclassical argument and involves only the vacuum at the horizon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle yes. But it is very, very hard:
[Computational Complexity and Black Hole Horizons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5674)

Quote from the paper:

> Representing bulk physics by boundary data at a ﬁxed time is diﬃcult
>   for well known reasons. It is especially diﬃcult to represent the bulk
>   degrees of freedom behind the horizon. And ﬁnally it is
>   extraordinarily diﬃcult to represent them at late time. The diﬃculty
>   is connected with complexity and chaos. The purpose of this section is
>   to explain these diﬃculties.

The conclusion of that section is, quote:

> The bad news of this section is that chaos and complexity make it
>   impractical to compute the gauge theory description of even a simple
>   low energy observable behind Bob’s horizon at late time. The good news
>   is that the diﬃculties are practical and do not present an
>   in-principle obstacle to describing the interior

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, if our current understanding of Hawking radiation is correct. The problem is that Hawking radiation is thermal. This means that it comes in a statistical ensemble of quantum states. In particular it can't carry information about the evolution of quantum states you dropped into the black hole. This is the origin of the famous [information paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox).

Of course nobody has solved the information paradox, although several [competing explanations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78682/is-the-firewall-paradox-really-a-paradox) have been advocated. It's conceivable that perhaps there is hidden information in Hawking radiation within a more complete understanding.

Comment: The article you linked to seems to say yes. "There are various ideas about how the paradox is solved. Since the 1997 proposal of the AdS/CFT correspondence, the predominant belief among physicists is that information is preserved and that Hawking radiation is not precisely thermal but receives quantum corrections."